# Problem with special characters Flash to XML

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3

By sending the below text block from Flash there are problems with the through PHP created XML output.

`(  )  *  +  ,  -  .  /  0  1    !   #    %    ‚    2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;    <  =  >  ?  @  A  B  C  D  E    F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O    P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y    Z  [  \  ]  ^  _    a  b  c    d  e ...`

I think some of the characters causing the problem. How to fix this problem?
Cheers

Comment: You are not actually telling us *what* the problem is. Not sure what kind of input you expect.

Comment: I'm guessing the `<` and `>` aren't escaped in the output and cause XML syntax errors/malformed documents. If they're not being used as XML metacharacters, they need to be encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: you need to wrap it in a cData tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all standalone characters are supported as valid XML, specifically

- Left Angle Bracket (<)
- Right Angle Bracket (>)
- Double Quote (")
- Apostrophe (')
- Ampersand (&)

So if any of your input contains that and you're just trying to shove it into the XML, then you're going to get malformed XML.  You need to run your input through a conversion function ([htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)).

Or you could, as The_asMan suggested, wrap all of your input in a CDATA section.  Your text won't be parsed as XML that way.

Comment: Wow for a newbie this is tough. Is this the right way to do it in PHP? `$mycaption = $_REQUEST['caption'];
$mycaption = htmlentities($mycaption, ENT_QUOTES);` Thanks for your support.

Comment: See my edit. You should be using htmlspecialchars.  So your code would be `$mycaption = htmlspecialchars($mycaption, ENT_QUOTES);`